# QT reading file line by line

Tags: c++, qt, readline, qtextstream

I need to read the contents of a file line by line.

Sample.txt:

```
#define <tabspace> temp <tabspace> 10
```

Code:

```
QFile file("D:\Sample.txt");
QTextStream in(&file);
QString str_Line = in.readLine();
```

`str_Line` contains `#definetemp10`

How to read the line with including the tab spaces? can any one please help me out?

Comment: My output should look like #define temp 10 (i.e) with the tab space

Comment: I edited the question to better see what is what. If I understood your intent wrong, please edit further!

Comment: `readLine` will certainly read and keep spaces. If your output is without them, there's something else going on! Try printing `std_Line.simplify()` and see if it then prints correctly (check the docs to see what it does).

Comment: Another debugging hint, print `std_Line.toLatin1().toHex()` (and check the docs to see what it does). As it is know, your question does not really have enough details to answer accurately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It solved my query.. Simplified returned the hidden white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the multiple whitespaces into a single white space. Use `QString::simplified()` or `QString::trimmed()`.

In your code add the below line,

```
QString str_Line = in.readLine();
str_Line.trimmed();//
str_Line.simplified();//
```